# How do I reference a method in a different class from a method in another class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I have a module and class in a file `lib/crawler/page-crawler.rb` that looks like this:

```
require 'oga'
require 'net/http'
require 'pry'

module YPCrawler
  class PageCrawler

    attr_accessor :url

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
    end

    def get_page_listings
      body = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@url))
      document = Oga.parse_html(body)
      document.css('div.result')
    end

    newpage = PageCrawler.new "http://www.someurl"
    @listings = newpage.get_page_listings
    @listings.each do |listing|
      bizname = YPCrawler::ListingCrawler.new listing['id']
    end
  end
end
```

Then I have another module & class in another file `lib/crawler/listing-crawler.rb` that looks like this:

```
require 'oga'
require 'pry'

module YPCrawler
  class ListingCrawler
    def initialize(id)
      @id = id
    end

    def extract_busines_name
      binding.pry
    end

  end
end
```

However, when I try to run this script `ruby lib/yp-crawler.rb` which executes the `page-crawler.rb` file above and works without the `YPCrawler` call, I get this error:

```
/lib/crawler/page-crawler.rb:23:in `block in <class:PageCrawler>': uninitialized constant YPCrawler::ListingCrawler (NameError)
```

The issue is on this line:

```
bizname = YPCrawler::ListingCrawler.new listing['id']
```

So how do I call that other from within my iterator in my `page-crawler.rb`?

**Edit 1**

When I just do `ListingCrawler.new listing['id'], I get the following error:

```
 uninitialized constant YPCrawler::PageCrawler::ListingCrawler (NameError)
```

**Edit 2**

Here is the directory structure of my project:

[image: directory-structure]

**Edit 3**

My `yp-crawler.rb` looks like this:

```
require_relative "yp-crawler/version"
require_relative "crawler/page-crawler"
require_relative "crawler/listing-crawler"

module YPCrawler
end
```

Comment: since `PageCrawler` and `ListingCrawler` defined within the same module I say `ListingCrawler.new listing['id']` should work just fine. Or try `require`ying `lib/crawler/page-crawler.rb` in the `lib/crawler/listing-crawler.rb`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I updated the question with results from that suggestion.

Comment: what about `require`ing part? Tried that one?

Comment: Note that they are in two different files, that share the same module named `YPCrawler`. I also tried `require` and `require_relative`. Neither work.

Comment: the error is the same when you require the file, right?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Yep. The only thing that changes is the name of the constant, and that is changed by the value I put here: `bizname = YPCrawler::ListingCrawler.new listing['id']`

Comment: Nope...no change. Still generating the same errors :(

Comment: that is strange, `require` should have worked. Could you please double check if you do not have the issue close to the one you had yeserday (file in the wrong place whatsoever?). Normally `require './listing_crawler.rb'` must work.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I have added a screenshot of the directory structure to the question. I am calling `ListingCrawler.new` from within the `lib/crawler/page-crawler.rb` file. Shouldn't my require statement within my `listing-crawler.rb` file look like: `require './page-crawler.rb'` or even just `require 'page-crawler'`, since both files are in the same directory?

Comment: This is definitely a `require` issue. Somehow the file isn't being included at runtime. Are you running this as a ruby-gem or just a stand-alone script?

Comment: On your `yp-crawler.rb`, require both files, in order: 

`require 'crawler/listing-crawler'` and `require 'crawler/page-crawler'`

Comment: 1) you have very strange naming of files, it should be underscored (`_`), not hyphened (`-`).. 2) Since you want to use `ListingCrawler` in `PageCrawler` require `listing_crawler` in it, also, require both files in `yp-crawler.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `yp-crawler.rb` file, based on the structure that you posted, you should have something like:

```
require 'yp-crawler/version'
require 'crawler/listing-crawler'
require 'crawler/page-crawler'
```

Comment: Genius. This worked. The issue I was having is that I had `page-crawler` and `listing-crawler` inverted. i.e. `page-crawler` was 2nd, and `listing-crawler` was third. Once I switched them, it works. How do I know what the right order is, going forward?

Comment: @marcamillion It first loaded page crawler, where you happened to have reference to listing-crawler (which is not loaded at the moment), thus, initialized error :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I realize that now. But how do I think about the load order going forward? Which should be loaded first, and why? Is it that I should load the file that will be doing all the of the executing last?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your **yp-crawler.rb** add the line:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/crawler/**/*.rb"].each { |file| load(file) }
```

That should automatically include all files in your **/crawler** directory at runtime. Might want to do the same for the other directories.

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: Does it matter where I put that line in my `yp-crawler.rb` file? I have updated the question with the contents of my `yp-crawler.rb` file, for you to see.

Comment: Usually you put it at the top. It basically dynamically loads all the files in your `/crawler` directory so you don't need to manually write a `require` statement every time you create a new file.

Comment: Ok...I tried that and it didn't work. However Icguida's answer did. Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: You answer is not all wrong. The problem with this approach is that you can't control the order in which the files will be loaded. If files were completely independent, this would work.